# Validate the path of an url

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to validate an url without domain, just the path and params.

The regular expression that I'm using do most of the work, but It has some errors that I dont know how to prevent (I'm pretty noob with regexp):

```
/^(\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/])+)$/i
```

The next example are correctly validated

```
/asd.jsp -> true
/asd/asd.jsp -> true
/asd/asd.jsp?bar=baz&inga=42&quux -> true
/asd/asd.jsp?bar=ba z&inga=42&quux -> false
```

But this ones arent correct ulrs and them gives me true too:

```
/asd/asd./jsp -> true :(
/asd/asd.jsp/ -> true :(
/asd./asd.jsp -> true :(
/asd///asd.jsp -> true :(
/asd/asd.jsp&bar=baz?inga=42?quux -> true :(
```

Do you recommend to use a function instead of a regex?

Very much thanks!

Comment: Take a look to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url). Just remove regex for the domain (search the 3rd dot).

Comment: `/asd/asd.jsp/` is a valid url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(\\/\\w+)+\\.\\w+(\\?(\\w+=[\\w\\d]+(&\\w+=[\\w\\d]+)+)+)*$
```

I already escaped special characters, so  you can directly use it in java.
By the way, */asd/asd.jsp?bar=baz&inga=42&quux* is not a valid URL.

Unescaped Regex:

```
^(\/\w+)+\.\w+(\?(\w+=[\w\d]+(&\w+=[\w\d]+)+)+)*$
```

Comment: I have changed your solution a bit to allow the value "/asd/asd.jsp" and just one parameter with "?":

`^(\/\w+)+\.\w+(\?(\w+=[\w\d]+(&\w+=[\w\d]+)*)+){0,1}$`

As a last request, is possible to allow too the values "/asd/" and "/asd"?

Very much thanks for your solution, is really great!

Comment: in javascript not working it has a bug , if length of the string is even it shows false@M. Abbas

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\/\w+)+(\.)?\w+(\?(\w+=[\w\d]+(&\w+=[\w\d]+)*)+){0,1}$
```

VALID:

```
/test
/test/test
/test.jsp
/test.jsp?v=1
/test.jsp?v=1&v=2
/test/test.jsp?v=1&v=2
```

INVALID:

```
/test/test./jsp
/test/test.jsp/
/test./test.jsp
/test///test.jsp
```