# Regex: validate a URL path with no query params

Tags: python, regex, url, path

I'm not a regex expert and I'm breaking my head trying to do one that seems very simple and works in python 2.7: validate the path of an URL (no hostname) without the query string. In other words, a string that starts with /, allows alphanumeric values and doesn't allow any other special chars except these: `/`, `.`,  `-`

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469882/validate-the-path-of-an-url) that is very similar to what I need but for me isn't working at all, I can test with for example `aaa` and it will return true even if it doesn't start with `/`.

The current regex that I have kinda working is this one:

```
[^/+a-zA-Z0-9.-]
```

but it doesn't work with paths that don't start with `/`. For example:

- `/aaa` -> true, this is ok
- `/aaa/bbb` -> true, this is ok
- `/aaa?q=x` -> false, this is ok
- `aaa` -> true, this is NOT ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex you've defined is a character class. Instead, try:

```
^\/[/.a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```

Comment: The difference here being, that you require the string to begin with `/` (`^` means begin-of-line) and that you've added the `+` and end-of-line anchor `$`. Which makes the whole character-class capture optional

Comment: `^\/[\/\.a-zA-Z0-9\-]+$`, the `/`, `.`, and `-` should be escaped.

Comment: @Jon - You are right about escaping ``/`` in many implementations, but in Python, it need not be escaped. ``.`` need not be escaped either, as long as it's within a character class, at least in any implementation I know of. And ``-`` need not be escaped if it is specified first or last in a character class. Of course, not that it hurts to escape "too much," but just wanted to clarify these details.

Comment: you might want to use `\A` and `\z` to match the beginning and end of a potentially multi-line string

Answer (score 3):

> In other words, a string that starts with /, allows alphanumeric
>   values and doesn't allow any other special chars except these: /, ., -

You are missing some characters that are valid in URLs

```
import string
import urllib
import urlparse

valid_chars = string.letters + string.digits + '/.-~'
valid_paths = []

urls = ['http://www.my.uni.edu/info/matriculation/enroling.html',
    'http://info.my.org/AboutUs/Phonebook',
    'http://www.library.my.town.va.us/Catalogue/76523471236%2Fwen44--4.98',
    'http://www.my.org/462F4F2D4241522A314159265358979323846',
        'http://www.myu.edu/org/admin/people#andy',
        'http://www.w3.org/RDB/EMP?*%20where%20name%%3Ddobbins']

for i in urls:
   path = urllib.unquote(urlparse.urlparse(i).path)
   if path[0] == '/' and len([i for i in path if i in valid_chars]) == len(path):
        valid_paths.append(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

^(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9.-&&[^/]]*)+$

Seems to work. See the picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try posting some more code. I can't figure out how you're using your regex from your question. What's confusing me is, your re expression `[^/+a-zA-Z0-9.-]` basically says:

Match a single character if it is:

not a `/`
or a-z (caps and lower both) or 0-9
or a dot or a dash

It doesn't quite make sense to me without knowing how you use it, as it only matches a single charactre and not a whole URL string.

I'm not sure I understand why you cannot start with a `/`.

Comment: Because it's an url path. Right after host, there must be a slash. Let's say you have var ajax_path='http://example.com'+unvalidated_path . If the path doesn't start with /, malicious user could insert ".", like .externaldomain.com and perform XSS attack.